# Merge PDF annotations from two files

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have two versions of the same PDF document. One has annotations that I did on it while reading it on my laptop, while the other has annotations that I did on a tablet. Now I want to merge these annotations into the same file.

I know that Adobe Acrobat allows me to do this (see for example [this answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/79412/31113)). Is there any software I can use in Ubuntu that will allow me to do this?

For what it is worth, I am using Xodo on the tablet.

Comment: With a bit of luck you can install Adobe Acrobat for Windows with Wine.

Comment: I really don't want to use wine. Is there any other alternative @alfC?

Comment: @bekco that link posted was marked as a "Blacklisted website" so I doubt it will do what you need.

Comment: @Rinzwind Where is it marked as "blacklisted website"? I opened it and it looked fine, I was about to install it.

Comment: By the AU bot. https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/120914/smokedetector see https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/82439 and https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39626266#39626266

Comment: Aren't annotations to pdfs "decodeable" only by the application that added them?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109895/text-annotations-and-image-additions-to-pdf-file-using-free-software.

Comment: @DKBose Adobe Acrobat is able to import annotations done in a variety of programs. I have tested annotating the PDF with Foxit, Xodo, Dropbox PDF viewer, PDF Reader Pro (a Mac app), and others. In every case, I can import the annotations into a copy of the file using Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

At least `okular` stores comments as objects of `/Type/Annot`, see these examples for the syntax:

```
17 0 obj
<<
/Type/Annot
/Rect[67.023 756.168 85.203 774.333]
/Subtype/Text
/M(D:20170828091301)
/T(■ somebody)
/Contents(■ text)
/NM(okular-{8ff65cc1-7b89-45c6-8adf-1aa6cec06cd0})
/F 4
/C[1 1 0]
/CA 0.5
/Border[0 0 1]
/P 20 0 R
>>
endobj
```

---

```
18 0 obj
<<
/Type/Annot
/Rect[37.7 597.841 236.675 615.979]
/Subtype/FreeText
/DA(/Invalid_font 10 Tf)
/M(D:20170828091316)
/T(■ somebody)
/Contents(■ text)
/NM(okular-{50420111-1c05-4e07-8db5-08deffb0ec7e})
/F 20
/C[1 1 0]
/CA 0.5
/Border[0 0 1]
/Q 0
/IT/FreeText
/P 20 0 R
>>
endobj
```

Those objects are linked to pages using a command like `/Annots 14 0 R`, which is how [this script](https://gist.github.com/stefanschmidt/5248592) deletes all comments in a given `pdf` file, it simply deletes all the `/Annots` lines:

```
pdftk original.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress
LANG=C sed -n '/^\/Annots/!p' uncompressed.pdf > stripped.pdf
pdftk stripped.pdf output final.pdf compress
```

If you dive really deep into the structure of your specific `pdf` documents – just open them with a text editor –, you may be able to understand what's going on and manage to manipulate your documents with e. g. `sed`, however I seriously doubt there exists a solution that fits every type of `pdf` document here. For what it's worth, (at least for my test file) the following oneliner gives you the comments of `input.pdf` in a terminal:

```
pdftk input.pdf output - uncompress | sed '/^\/Contents (/!d'
```

Add `>> comments` to the end of that line to store the output in a file named `comments` instead.

Comment: I am awarding you the bounty so it is not lost. But I hope there is a better way!

Comment: @becko As PDF is far from being a well-defined format with a clear and stable syntax unfortunately that's unlikely. Sorry for not having better news.

Comment: Well, Adobe Acrobat does it pretty well, which shows it is possible. Actually I am using Xodo to make annotations, on a tablet. Maybe Xodo stores comments in the same way as Okular?

Comment: Are you sure Adobe Acrobat can do that for comments added in other programs? I wouldn't count on it… I just tested and Xodo stores comments similarly to Okular, so the last command in my answer is able to display them.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat works fine with Xodo, which is the combo I have been using, on a Mac (where I have Adobe Acrobat). If Xodo uses the same format as Okular that is good news! Thanks